how to intercept outgoing SQL statements using Quarkus + Hibernate Reactive (StatementInspector)
How can I intercept (and modify) the outgoing SQL statements using Quarkus and Hibernate Reactive?
I tried to do so by implementing a custom StatementInspector, but somehow the inspector is not executed, I guess (Quarkus) Hibernate Reactive does not follow the same principles here.

This question is similar to: SQL inspection/injection in Hibernate Reactive. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
